# An icon is not showing on action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons

I am trying to show an icon on action bar. When I add an icon to the action bar the preview of menu_main.xml shows that icon on action bar. Here is the menu_main.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".ManiActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_create_order"
        android:title="@string/action_create_order"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new_event"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

and here is the preview of menu_main.xml
[menu_main.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYE9z.jpg)

But when I run the app on emulator it does not show the icon on action bar instead it shows the icon's title in overflow area.
here is the screenshot of emulator
[emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOVtY.jpg)

Here is MainActivity.java code

```
package com.example.bitsandpizzas;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

And here is the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: set app:showAsAction="always" for both menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Because `MainActivity` extends `android.app.Activity` and not `AppCompatActivity`. The `MenuInflater` of `android.app.Activity` isnot parsing the `app:showAsAction="always"` attribute. There are two options to solve this.

#### Option 1 (*Recommanded*)

Extend `AppCompatActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

#### Option 2

Use `android` namespace in menu resource xml:

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

Comment: But I have a question when I extends AppCompatActivity the app crashes.